# Something like `libconfig` for Java?

Tags: java, configuration, configuration-files, libconfig

I'm looking for Java framework like [**libconfig**](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/). I like its [simple human readable configuration](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/test.cfg.txt) files and also that I can create complex setting values composed from arrays, lists, groups.

Is there anything similar for Java (not XML) ?

Comment: why not use resource bundles?

Comment: @fmucar It doesn't seems to be able parse group-like values as libconfig does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple JSON-esque format; why not just use JSON?

[Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) supports a similarly-formatted config using [PropertyListConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/plist/PropertyListConfiguration.html).

A Groovy-based [ConfigSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper) might be suitable if you're considering JVM, rather than Java-the-language, solutions. JRuby and JavaScript etc. has similar implementations.

Comment: Commons Configuration and plist seems to be what i'm looking for, but i can't find any tutorial how to use it

Comment: It seems that i'll end with JSON and maybe google's gson. Thanks :)